# How can I prove $\Gamma\vdash(\psi_1\lor\psi_2)$ is equivalent to $\Gamma\vdash\psi_1$ or $\Gamma\vdash\psi_2$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Hi I'm learning first order logic, and would like to prove that $\Gamma\vdash(\psi_1\lor\psi_2)$ is equivalent to $\Gamma\vdash\psi_1$ or $\Gamma\vdash\psi_2$ using logic axiom of the following:

1. $((\phi_1\to(\phi_2\to\phi_3))\to((\phi_1\to\phi_2)\to(\phi_1\to\phi_3)))$
2. $(\phi_1\to\phi_1)$
3. $(\phi_1\to(\phi_2\to\phi_1))$
4. $(\phi_1\to((\lnot\phi_1)\to\phi_2))$
5. $(((\lnot\phi_1)\to\phi_1)\to\phi_1)$
6. $((\lnot\phi_1)\to(\phi_1\to\phi_2))$
7. $(\phi_1\to((\lnot\phi_2)\to(\lnot(\phi_1\to\phi_2))))$

The equivalent expression for $(\psi_1\lor\psi_2)$ is $((\lnot\psi_1)\to\psi_2)$

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You can't prove it because it's not the case. E.g. $A \vee B \vdash A \vee B$ using axiom 2, but $A \vee B \not\vdash A$, and similarly $A \vee B \not\vdash B$.

Comment: @z.a.k. which means $\Gamma\vdash\psi_1$ or $\Gamma\vdash\psi_2$ can lead to $\Gamma\vdash(\psi_1\lor\psi_2)$, but not the other way around??

Comment: That's right, one direction works. E.g. if $\Gamma \vdash \psi_1$ then $\Gamma \vdash \psi_2 \vee \psi_1$. You get this by applying axiom 3 to have $\Gamma \vdash \psi_1 \rightarrow (\neg\psi_2 \rightarrow \psi_1)$, then using modus ponens together with $\Gamma \vdash \psi_1$ to conclude $\Gamma \vdash \neg\psi_2 \rightarrow \psi_1$. The other direction very much does not (for the reasons explained in my previous comment).

Comment: @z.a.k. thanks a lot!!

Comment: Although what you asked does not hold over the classical logic, it holds for the *intuitionistic logic.* That is, if you can prove $\phi\lor\psi$ from the intuitionistic propositional logic (or predicate logic), then you have a proof for $\phi$ or that for $\psi$. It is known as a disjunction property.

Comment: @HanulJeon The disjunction property holds for proofs from no hypotheses. It doesn't work for $\Gamma\vdash$ when $\Gamma$ is non-empty, as Z.A.K.'s comment shows.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Ah, you are right. I did not see $\Gamma$ throughout the question.